# React : I always send the previous state o my backend, even with "previousState"

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am using this code to send data to the back-end and it works, on the other hand it is always the previous state which is sent to the back-end. Even using previousState, it doesn't change anything. Anyone have any idea why?

```
const Form = ({ form }) => {
  const [userSignup, setUserSignup] = useState({
    user_firstname: "",
    user_lastname: "",
    user_email: "",
    user_password: "",
  });
    
  // Signup / login functions
  const signup = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Always the previousState, even with previousState 
      setUserSignup((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          user_firstname: refSignupFirstName.current.value,
          user_lastname: refSignupLastName.current.value,
          user_email: refSignupEmail.current.value,
          user_password: refSignupPassword.current.value,
        };
      });
      await POST(ENDPOINTS.USER_SIGNUP, userSignup)
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error during registration... : ", err);
    }
  };
    
  // Input refs
  const refSignupFirstName = useRef(null);
  const refSignupLastName = useRef(null);
  const refSignupEmail = useRef(null);
  const refSignupPassword = useRef(null);


return (*my form...*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem.

```
      await POST(ENDPOINTS.USER_SIGNUP, userSignup)
```

You can't expect the `userSignup` is the new one, instead you already have a new one in front of you.

```
        {
          ...prevState,
          user_firstname: refSignupFirstName.current.value,
          user_lastname: refSignupLastName.current.value,
          user_email: refSignupEmail.current.value,
          user_password: refSignupPassword.current.value,
        }
```

The step is the following, assemble the new state, use it afterwards, but don't ever think of the old state anymore ;)

```
  const newState = { ...prevState }
  POST(newState)
  // not the below version
  POST(state)
```

NOTE:

`setUserSignup` isn't a straight forward assignment, like `a = 1`. It's actually a request to make an assignment. The assignment takes time and could be revoked. That's why you can't expect the state has already switched to the new state right after this statement.

People normally refer it as async call due to the behavior of this call, however it's more complicated than that. It's a sync call but behaving in async way. Suffice to say, it has async behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! but i dont understand where am i supposed to put "const newState = { ...prevState }"  (sorry, i'm a newbie)